# Cannot connect to real site ssl errror when using SSL bump

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, squid

In our office, we are using squid to restrict users to connect only particular web sites and urls. If a user is connecting a web page via https, url_regex acl will not work. In a https request, we have control over domain only. But we need to restrict on url level. So, we used ssl bump to intercept the https requests. Its working fine, but we got some ssl warnings in browser.

[image]

Is this possible to intercept a ssl connection in bump without any browser warnings?

**squid configuration file**

```
    #
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
#debug_options ALL,3
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

#allowing .zopert.com domains
acl trustedDomains dstdomain -i "/etc/squid/trusted_domains.txt"

#excluded domains
acl excludedDomains dstdomain -i "/etc/squid/excluded_domains.txt"

#allowing grid console.
acl adminConsole urlpath_regex \/admin\/

#allowed urls
acl trustedUrls url_regex -i "/etc/squid/allowed_urls.txt"


# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
http_port 3129 ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid/test.crt key=/etc/squid/test.key

# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl HTTPS proto HTTPS 
#

# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
#http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
#http_access allow allowurls
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports
# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed

#allowing trusted domains(.zopert.com) only.

http_access allow trustedDomains adminConsole 
http_access allow trustedDomains trustedUrls

#allowing static domains

http_access allow excludedDomains


#ssl_bump deny trustedDomains
http_access allow CONNECT trustedDomains

#http_access allow CONNECT
always_direct allow HTTPS 

#ssl_bump allow adminConsole
ssl_bump allow trustedDomains

#we don't need to intercept other ssl sites.
ssl_bump deny all

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
#sslproxy_cert_error allow all
#http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
http_access deny CONNECT

#We recommend you to use at least the following line.
#hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320


logformat squid  %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %>A %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %un %Sh/%<A %mt
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL bump is doing a man-in-the-middle attack and the browser is complaining about this, which is the expected behavior. If you don't want this you need to import the CA (test.crt) as trusted in all browsers.